# How to create foreign key constraint without relationship in Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have the following 2 tables:

```
+-------+  +------------------------------+
| users |  |        blocked_users         |
+-------+  +------------------------------+
|   id  |  | id, user_id, blocked_user_id | 
+-------+  +------------------------------+
```

My `User` class has the following relationship defined:

```
/**
 * Users the instance user has blocked.
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *      targetEntity="BlockedUser",
 *      mappedBy="blocker",
 *      fetch="EXTRA_LAZY",
 *      cascade={"persist", "remove"},
 *      orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 *
 * @var BlockedUser[]|Collection
 */
  protected $blockedUsers;
```

I haven't defined a `blockedByUsers` relationship, since a user should't know who blocked them. However, when I deleted a User who has been blocked I get a foreign key exception. I could fix the exception by adding another `User::$blockedByUsers` relationship, but as I said I don't believe that should exist.

Is there any other way to create the cascading foreign key relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the foreign key on the `blocked_users` table when you define the relationship from `blocked_user_id` to `user`:

```
@JoinColumn(name="blocked_user_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
```

The `onDelete` option will cascade deletion as you expect.